# Understanding delegate vs block. (refactor code to use delegation instead of block)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I found an example online of how one could separate the datasource of a UITableview to make code more reusable. However in this code it uses a block instead of a delegate to update the cells. So far in my project I have been using delegates so for consistency I would like it to remain this way so I would love if someone could explain better blocks and help me refactor the example code below to include `delegates` instead of the block. The example I am using is from http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html ;

```
//
//  ArrayDataSource.h
//  objc.io example project (issue #1)
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


typedef void (^TableViewCellConfigureBlock)(id cell, id item);


@interface ArrayDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)anItems
 cellIdentifier:(NSString *)aCellIdentifier
 configureCellBlock:(TableViewCellConfigureBlock)aConfigureCellBlock;

- (id)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

.m

```
//
//  ArrayDataSource.h
//  objc.io example project (issue #1)
//

#import "ArrayDataSource.h"


@interface ArrayDataSource ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *cellIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, copy) TableViewCellConfigureBlock configureCellBlock;

@end


@implementation ArrayDataSource

- (id)init
{
    return nil;
}

- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)anItems
 cellIdentifier:(NSString *)aCellIdentifier
 configureCellBlock:(TableViewCellConfigureBlock)aConfigureCellBlock
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.items = anItems;
        self.cellIdentifier = aCellIdentifier;
        self.configureCellBlock = [aConfigureCellBlock copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.items[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
}


#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
    id item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.configureCellBlock(cell, item);
    return cell;
}

@end
```

And its usage in the `UIViewController` would be;

```
void (^configureCell)(PhotoCell*, Photo*) = ^(PhotoCell* cell, Photo* photo) {
cell.label.text = photo.name;
};
photosArrayDataSource = [[ArrayDataSource alloc] initWithItems:photos
                                            cellIdentifier:PhotoCellIdentifier
                                        configureCellBlock:configureCell];
self.tableView.dataSource = photosArrayDataSource;
```

I try to learn something new everyday and it would be great if someone could help. One day at a time I hope to improve as a developer :)

I understand the separating of the datasource, but the use of a block instead of a delegate is new (weird) to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, in your example, the ArrayDataSource class is a "generic" class to be used for all your UITableView's datasources.

If you look closely at the implementation of ArrayDataSource (ArrayDataSource.m), you'll see it calls the classical methods of a UITableViewDatasource (`numberOfRowsInSection:`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`...). But when the generic class has to configure the content of the cell for a specific indexPath, it doesn't know what to do with the `id item`, so it calls a specific block (with `self.configureCellBlock(cell, item);`) to externalize this behavior from the generic class.

The idea of blocks is like functions pointers, you're only telling the generic ArrayDatasource class, what function to call when it has to configure the content of a cell on the line `self.configureCellBlock(cell, item);`. In your case, the cell will display the photo's name (`cell.label.text = photo.name;`).

So, in this case, you're still using the datasource concept of a UITableView in `ArrayDatasource` class, and you can put all your needs for a default `UITableViewDatasource` in the `ArrayDataSource.m` (like implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and so on...), to prevent a copy-paste for all your tableView's datasource (in the case of your app has many `UITableView`). 
The aim of blocks here is not to replace the datasource concept, but more a convenient way to tell a generic class what to do...

I hope I'm clear, but it's not always easy to explain such concepts ! :)